# How to use filters with if condition in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have the following Django template.

```
{% load custom_tags %}
<ul>
{% for key, value in value.items %}
<li> {{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I need to check for the value and do some modifications.

If the value is True , instead of value I have to print Applied , else if it False I need to print Not Applied.

I can do this to get there.

```
{% if value %}
  APPLIED
{% else %}
   NOT APPLIED 
{% endif %}
```

How to achieve this using filters?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`yesno`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno) filter:

```
{{ value|yesno:"APPLIED,NOT APPLIED" }}
```